# Non-blocking TCP socket and flushing right after send?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, nonblocking, flush

I am using Windows socket for my application(winsock2.h). Since the blocking socket doesn't let me control connection timeout, I am using non-blocking one. Right after send command I am using shutdown command to flush(I have to). My timeout is 50ms and the thing I want to know is if the data to be sent is so big, is there a risk of sending only a portion of data or sending nothing at all? Thanks in advance...

```
    hSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    u_long iMode=1;
    ioctlsocket(hSocket,FIONBIO,&iMode);
    connect(hSocket, (sockaddr*)(&sockAddr),sockAddrSize);
    send(hSocket, sendbuf, sendlen, 0);
    shutdown(hSocket, SD_BOTH);
    Sleep(50);
    closesocket(hSocket);
```

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure that the connection timeouts work just fine with blocking sockets as well - I do this all the time within client threads - if disconnected, they loop round a connect() attempt and a sleep(2000), continually retrying to connect, until one succeeds.  The connect timeout is anyway not relevant to socket writes after the connect() has succeeded, so I assume you mean a form of write timeout?  If so, I have never tried anything like that - I don't use connect/disconnect protocols, (except for browser/HTTP!), because of the bad performance, (especially on high-latency links).

Comment: You can timeout a blocking mode connect with select(). You don't have to call shutdown() to flush. TCl does not lose data, otherwise the Internet wouldn't work, e.g. this forum, Amazon, Google, etc. Your question is based on false premisses.

Comment: You are "selecting" state of socket and checking for disconnection right? I want to be sending data as fast as possible. Also the 2 possible cases are: server waits too long to accept connection or receive. So both connecting and writing should be done in max of 50ms since the time is very important in my situation. I have to flush both write and read streams because the server keeps sending me unnecessarly big data and I have limited internet connection. Actually I don't even want a single byte from the server :)

Comment: @EJP By checking from another thread? So let's say the socket was blocked in connect line. If another thread closes the socket when timeout reached, the block is released?

Comment: @GunDenizAkkoc Yes and yes, but even even if you use non-blocking connect there's nothing that says you have to stay in non-blocking mode for the receives. And as you are following your shutdown by a close, the shutdown is 100% redundant, ditto the sleep.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks to EJP and Martin, now I have created a second thread to check. Also in the code I posted in my question, I added "counter=0;" line after the "send" line and removed shutdown. It works just as I wanted now. It never waits more than 50ms :) Really big thanks

```
unsigned __stdcall SecondThreadFunc( void* pArguments )
```

{

```
while(1)
{
    counter++;
    if (counter > 49)
    {
        closesocket(hSocket);
        counter = 0;
        printf("\rtimeout");
    }

    Sleep(1);
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: I really decline to be blamed for this. It doesn't answer your question. It doesn't behave the way you think. All the data in flight will still be sent, and the close signal will then be sent. It does not implement a timeout of any kind.

Answer (score 1):

> Non-blocking TCP socket and flushing right after send?

There is no such thing as flushing a TCP socket.

> Since the blocking socket doesn't let me control connection timeout

False. You can use `select()` on a blocking socket.

> I am using non-blocking one.

*Non sequitur.*

> Right after send command I am using shutdown command to flush(I have to).

You don't have to, and `shutdown()` doesn't flush anything.

> My timeout is 50ms

Why? The time to send data depends on the size of the data. Obviously. It does not make any sense whatsoever to use a fixed timeout for a send.

> and the thing I want to know is if the data to be sent is so big, is there a risk of sending only a portion of data or sending nothing at all?

In blocking mode, all the data you provided to `send()` will be sent if possible. In non-blocking mode, the amount of data represented by the return value of `send()` will be sent, if possible. In either case the connection will be reset if the send fails. Whatever timeout mechanism you superimpose can't possibly change any of that: specifically, closing the socket asynchronously after a timeout will only cause the close to be appended to the data being sent. It will *not* cause the send to be aborted.

Your code wouldn't pass any code review known to man. There is zero error checking; the sleep is completely pointless; and shutdown before close is redundant. If the sleep is intended to implement a timeout, it doesn't.

> I want to be sending data as fast as possible.

You can't. TCP implements flow control. There is exactly nothing you can do about that. You are rate-limited by the receiver.

> Also the 2 possible cases are: server waits too long to accept connection

There is no such case. The client can complete a connection before the server ever calls `accept().` If you're trying to implement a connect timeout shorter than the default of about a minute, use `select().`

> or receive.

Nothing you can do about that: see above.

> So both connecting and writing should be done in max of 50ms since the time is very important in my situation.

See above. It doesn't make sense to implement a fixed timeout for operations that take variable time. And 50ms is far too short for a connect timeout. If that's a real issue you should keep the connection open so that the connect delay only happens once: in fact you should keep TCP connections open as long as possible anyway.

> I have to flush both write and read streams

You can't. There is no operation in TCP that will flush either a read stream or a write stream.

> because the server keeps sending me unnecessarly big data and I have limited internet connection.

Another *non sequitur.* If the server sends you data, you have to read it, otherwise you will stall the server, and that doesn't have anything to do with flushing your own write stream.

> Actually I don't even want a single byte from the server

Bad luck. You have to read it. [If you were on BSD Unix you could shutdown the socket for input, which would cause data from the server to be thrown away, but that doesn't work on Windows: it causes the server to get a connection reset.]

Comment: Oh the code is not complete, the code I posted is only for the second thread. If the 3 way handshake is completed and the data to be sent is out of my computer(to wires) I simply reset the counter to zero. So it actually does work. Another thing is, select accepts the timeout in seconds not miliseconds. Lastly, as far as I remember I meant flushing data from the buffer. I am just using no delay option now...

Comment: Your method works in the sense of not failing, but it doesn't do what you claim to need: enforce a write timeout. All it does is gratuitously close a working socket. Re 'another thing', you are mistaken. `select()` accepts a timeout in the form of a `timeval` structure, which has fields for both seconds and microseconds. `shutdown()` still doesn't flush a socket, which can *only* mean flushing the socket send buffer. Only normal transmission or a reset can do that.