# Flush a socket in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, winsock2

I tried to flush a socket after calling to `send` function in c++.
I used `winsock2.h` library.

I need to send the data immediatly after the send message, but I can not find any function like `flash` function.

I am trying to send messages to a device and it expect receiving messages one by one.
I mean that if I sending two messages in the sender like "MessageOne" and "MessageTwo", the receiver received "MessageOneMessageTwo" that is not seperate, and the device not recognize the commands.

So how can I do that?

Comment: You can check this [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491147/non-blocking-socket-and-flushing-right-after-send) or Go through the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506(v=vs.85).aspx) regarding the same

Comment: If the socket is TCP then the first thing to do is disable Nagle algorithm

Comment: If you don't need to do anything else on the socket then closing it would flush it (if linger is not set in socket options).

Comment: @bobah here the FAQ regarding disabling Nagle http://www.tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/intermediate.html#disable-nagle

Comment: @Sergey - not sure why you addressed your comment to me, but thanks. If you implied that disabling Nagle algorithm is a bad idea then I can only reply with "right tool for the right task", Nagle algo is disabled in most low latency messaging software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing you can do on the *send* side to make the *receive* side receive messages 'one by one'. Is entirely the receive side responsibility to properly reconstruct the sent frames ('messages'). Receive code must know the message length *somehow* (entirely protocol specific) and receive as much data as appropriate to construct an entire frame (usually achieved by posting recv with a specified length and specified that is interested only on the entire buffer, eg. `MSG_WAITALL` flag). I find it very hard to believe your device does not know how to handle this, and if that's indeed the case there is literally *nothing* you can do. I find it somehow more likely that you do not understand the device/protocol requirements and you're asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "flush" functionality for sockets. If you need to send two messages in rapid succession then just send them. If it's a TCP socket then they will arrive in the correct order (the order you send them in).

This pattern is actually not uncommon; First send a message header followed by a separate send of the message data.

Comment: I send message to a device and it execpts to receive one message at a time.

Comment: Even if you sent all the data you had, there's no guarantee that it'd arrive all at once.

Comment: @Someone Do you mean that the TCP/IP stack on the receiving end only have a buffer enough for one single message? Or that the receiving program have? Either way, it's not a problem if using TCP, as the TCP can handle that.

Comment: @Someone What "inner buffer"? Could you please edit your question to include some code (or at lease pseudo-code) to show what you are doing? On both sender and receiver side?

Comment: The receiver is device and the sender is computer, I just want to send message to the device. The only issue is that the device can receive one command at a time.

Comment: @Someone And have you tried it? The _majority_ of all programs receiving messages receives one message at a time, does some processing, and then attempts to receive the next message. You don't describe your problem very well, which is why I asked for code. And that the "receiver" is a "device" doesn't matter, unless it's an extremely small device (i.e. the amount of RAM counts in one or two digit number of kilobytes).

Comment: Of course I checked it, I used sniffer to see all the network traffic, and I saw that my messages sended together and the device don't recognize them. Sorry for the confusing question.

Comment: @Someone Then you need to modify your protocol to separate messages. Either add a header containing the message size, or use a special separator that can never be in the messages. This is not a problem with the communication or network stack, but purely a protocol specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there really isn't a "flush" ability. the send function returns how many  bytes are sent, so you could iterate a loop until all the bytes are sent.

Edit:
To add to what I've read you want from other users. The only way I know of to increase the "internal buffer" (flushing it is something winsock does on its own) is setsockopt, using the so_sendbuf option.

Article relating to it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I dont want to increase it, I just want to send my message immediatly after calling to send function. I dont want that the mesasge will wait in the socket buffer.

Comment: Out-side of shutting down winsock, there isn't a way to flush it. And even that isn't guaranteed to flush it. My option removes the issue you had with the inner buffer. However, in theory you could make it tiny as to try and trick it into sending early, but again that's not guaranteed to work either.

Answer (score 0):

The precise answer to your packet scheme question with example from [Winsock FAQ](http://www.tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/intermediate.html#packetscheme)

Answer (score 0):

set socket options to NDELAY on the send side